# How to extract/share some common logic/sampler etc from many jmeter jmx files?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2, ruby-jmeter

If there are many jmeter scripts(jmx files) in a stress project for different cases run,  how to maintain the common jmeter code which can be shared by each jmx?

For example, many jmx files have same thread group,  http sampler,  config elements (header manager, Authorization manager etc) ?

Any way to only edit once and apply for all jmx scripts? I couldn't find the related jmeter doc about this?   wonder if jmeter jmx file supports any share code dynamic load/management?
Any suggestions are very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My expectation is that you're looking for the [Module Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller). In conjunction with [Test Fragments](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) you will be able to re-use sequences of the Test Elements either in current Test Plan or even in different .jmx scripts.

See [Using JMeter Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller) article for detailed information if needed

Comment: Thanks for your answer,   will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the [Include Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller). That way you can combine different jmx files to be run from one 'master' file. There are some things to keep in mind, but check the manual for that.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answers,  the  Test Fragments may meet my requirements.